# Do all stochastic volatility models capture volatility smile?

Tags: options, stochastic-volatility, volatility-smile, sabr

I started reading SABR model recently. 
In Wiki page, it states that the [SABR model can capture volatility smile in derivative market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABR_volatility_model). 
However, I do not see how it does so.

Comment: What exactly don't you see?

Comment: How does SABR model capture volatility smile? In other words, which part of the model shows that it captures volatility smile?

Comment: Take a look at the implied volatility expansion for the SABR model in the same Wiki link you posted. For $\alpha = 0, \beta \neq 1$ you don't have a stochastic volatility model but a CEV model which is a local volatility model. That already gives a smile. For $\beta = 1, \alpha = 0$ you will have no smile since it is then the Black-Scholes model. For $\beta = 1, \alpha \neq 0$ you have a stochastic volatility model and therefore also a smile.

Comment: @ilovevolatility Perhaps I should rephrase my question: Does all stochastic volatility models capture volatility smile?

Comment: Yes, and I suppose your next question will be why, so I am thinking how to best answer that. I'll let you know when I have a simple answer for that.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to try to answer your more general question "Do all SV models generate a smile?" which you put in one of the comments. (Maybe edit also the title of your question if you want, if my answer is satisfactory.)

I will take zero correlation between asset and the volatility process to start with. The generalisation to non-zero correlation is straightforward (but more tedious).

Let $\bar{\sigma}$ denote future realised volatility. If volatility is stochastic, it will have a distribution. The price of a vanilla option is
$$
C(S,K) = E[(S_T - K)_+]
$$
By conditioning we can write
\begin{align}
C(S,K) &= E[(S_T - K)_+] \\
&= E[E[(S_T - K)_+] | \bar{\sigma}] \\
&= E[C^{BS}(S,K,\bar{\sigma})]
\end{align}

Since the Black-Scholes vanilla option price is monotonic in volatility, we can always find a parameter, call it $\Sigma$, such that
$$
C(S,K) = C^{BS}(S,K,\Sigma(K))
$$
whatever the value of $C(S,K)$ may be.
Hence,
$$
C^{BS}(S,K,\Sigma(K)) = E[C^{BS}(S,K,\bar{\sigma})],\quad \forall K
$$
Thus, if volatility is **not** stochastic, then
$$
C^{BS}(S,K,\Sigma(K)) = C^{BS}(S,K,\bar{\sigma}),\quad \forall K
$$
But since the Black-Scholes price formula is monotonic in volatility, and $\bar{\sigma}$ does not depend on $K$ this must mean that,
$$
\Sigma(K) = \bar{\sigma} \,\, \forall K \Rightarrow \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial K} =0
$$
So, if volatility is not stochastic then no smile. Hence not(no smile) implies not(not stochastic).

Hope this makes sense.

EDIT: I should have added one maybe two assumptions to make this "proof" completely airtight since other non SV models can also give a smile, but under the assumption that the assets can only follow pure SV models (potentially with zero volatility of volatility) then the proof is OK.

Comment: Where is the zero correlation between asset and volatility used in your proof?

Comment: In the conditioning part.

Comment: Beautiful proof!